# Automation testing for windows and web?

Tags: automation, functional-testing, windows

I am looking for an automation testing tool that checks the following features:

1. Windows application functional testing on local desktop
2. Web-based functional testing
3. No coding required, to be used by testers with no coding experience
4. Record and run would be easy for GUI, but for object based testing some features to write simple words without coding without syntax problems

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend QTP as it can be used without any need for coding. The testers will just record and play back the recorded tests.

I don't understand point four well. I hope that my answer sheds some light and point you into the right direction

Answer (score 0):

TestComplete is the way to go for this. It's strong points is everything you're looking for it seems. There is a 30 day free trial too and a bunch of content to get you up to speed. No coding required. http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools/